# How do I test the translations I am making for 12.04?

Tags: launchpad, translation

I want to download latest translations from Launchpad of particular language for Ubuntu 12.04. How to do that?

I've been adding translations to Marathi language. But the version in synaptic is not updated with latest translations. How to download latest version of language from Launchpad or synaptic?

Answer (score 2):

1. On each translation page you will have a "Download translation" link.

   Click that link and you will be asked about the download format.
2. Choose "MO format" and click "Request Download" button.

   A link to the translation file will be send over email in about one or two hours.

   For Romanian translations of Jokey, it will look like:
   http://launchpadlibrarian.net/37938137/ro_LC_MESSAGES_jockey.mo
3. Download the file and copy it over the existent Jockey translation file from your system.
4. The filename will give you a clue about where to copy the new MO file.

   ```
   sudo cp ro_LC_MESSAGES_jockey.mo /usr/share/locale-langpack/ro/LC_MESSAGES/jockey.mo
   ```

Source: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-translations/+faq/907